# C.S. Basics: Understanding Data Packets, Protocols, Wireshark

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocols, binary-data, wireshark

### The Quest

I'm trying to talk to a [SRCDS Server](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SRCDS) from node.js via the [RCON Protocol](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol).
The RCON Protocol seems to be explained enough, implementations can be found on the bottom of the site in every major programming language. Using those is simple enough, but **understanding** the protocol and develop a JS library is what I set out to do.

### Background

Being a self taught programmer, I skipped a lot of Computer Science Basics - learned only what I needed, to accomplish what I wanted. I started coding with PHP, eventually wrapped my head around OO, talked to databases etc. I'm currently programming with JavaScript, more specifically doing web stuff with node.js ..

### Binary Data?!?!

I've read and understood the absolute binary basics. But when it comes to the packet data I'm totally lost. I'd like to read and understand the wireshark output, but I can't make any sense if it. My biggest problem is probably that I don't understand what the binary representation of the various INT and STRING (char ..) from JS look like and how I convert from data I got from the server to something usable in the program.

### Help

So I'd be more than grateful if someone can point me to a tutorial on these topics. Tutorial as in "explanation that mere mortals can understand, preferably not written by a C.S. professor". :)
When I'm looking at the PHP reference implementation I see (too much) magic happening there which I can't translate to JS. Sending and reading data from a socket is no problem, but I need to know how PHPs unpack function works respectively how I can do that in JS with node.js.

So I hope you can see what I'm trying to accomplish here. First and foremost is understanding the whole theory needed to make implementing the protocol a breeze. But because I'm only good with scripting languages it would be incredibly helpful if someone could guide me a bit in the HOWTO part in PHP/JS..

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Shameless plug warning :) A lot of time has passed since the original post. This one shows up in most searches, so here is an updated version of the rcon: https://github.com/randunel/node-srcds-rcon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I applaud the low level protocol pursuit.

I'll tell you the path I took. My approach was to use the client and server that already spoke the protocol and use libpcap to do analysis. I created a library that was able to unpack the custom protocol I was analyzing during this phase.

Its super helpful to start with diagrams like this one:

[image: TCP Header]

From the wiki on TCP. Its an incredibly useful way to visualize the structure of the binary data. Its tightly packed, so slicing it apart requires attention to detail.

### Buffers and Binary

I read up on Buffer. Its the way you deal with Binary in node. http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/buffers.html -- the first thing to realize here is that buffers can be accessed bit by bit via array syntax, ie buffer[0] and such.

### Visualization

Its helpful to be able to dump your binary data into a hex representation. I used https://github.com/a2800276/hexy.js to achieve this.

### node_pcap

I grabbed https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap -- this is the equivalent to wireshark, but you can programmatically poke at all outgoing and incoming traffic. I added udp payload support: https://github.com/jmoyers/node_pcap/commit/2852a8123486339aa495ede524427f6e5302326d

I read through all mranney's "unpack" code https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap/blob/master/pcap.js#L116-171

I found https://github.com/rmustacc/node-ctype

I read through all their "unpack" code https://github.com/rmustacc/node-ctype/blob/master/ctio.js

Now, things to remember when you're looking through this stuff. Most of the time they're taking a binary Buffer representation and converting to a native javascript type, like say Number or String. They'll use advanced techniques to do so -- bitwise operations like shifts and such. You don't necessarily need to understand all that.

The key things are:

1) endianness -- the ordering of bits (network and host byte order can be reverse from each other) as this pertains to how things are unpacked

2) Javascript Number representation is quirky -- node-ctype goes into detail in the comments about how they convert the various number types in javascript's Number. Integer, float, double etc are all Number in javascript land.

In the end, its likely fine if you just USE these unpackers for your adventures. I ended up having to unpack things that weren't covered in these libraries, like GUIDs and such, and it was tremendously helpful to study the source.

### Isolate the traffic you're looking at

Filter, filter, filter. Target one host. Target one direction. Target one message type. Focus on stripping off data that has a known fixed length first -- often times the header in a protocol is a good place to start. Once you get the header unpacking into a nice json structure from binary, you are well on your way.

After that, its one field at a time, top to bottom, one message at a time. You can use [Buffer#slice](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/buffers.html#buffer.slice) and the unpack functions from node-ctype to grab each piece of data at a time.

Comment: Thank you _very much_ for the great insight into this topic! Both overview and links are incredibly helpful. Unfortunately I cannot upvote (yet). I will set your answer as accepted if no one is willing to contribute further insight into this. ;)